# Procedimentos para a sugestão de remoção de um tag que não tenha explicação

Tags: discussion, tags, best-practice, editing

Enquanto aguardava resposta a [uma questão que partilhei](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/6379/kit-de-unhas-de-onde-vem-esta-express%C3%A3o), recebi uma notificação de uma proposta de edição, que era somente a remoção de um tag (como vemos na imagem abaixo).

[image: Proposta de remoção de tag]

Uma vez procurando por [mais informações acerca do tag `origem-histórica`](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origem-hist%C3%B3rica), temos que o tag não tem qualquer indicação:

[image: Informações do tag]

Com base no que se entende por tag, nomeadamente por tag útil para a questão:

> help to define the topic of the question. Tags should help to describe what the question is about, not just what it contains.

Parece-me que, nesta situação, há espaço para que a questão esteja associada ao tag específico, apenas pelo sentido que atribuo ao tag (visto não haver explicação para a utilização do mesmo), pelo que não aprovei o "Edit".

---

Por forma a previnir este tipo de situações, uma vez que não me parece fácil ter um mapeamento dos tags atualizado (e com a sua devida classificação bem definida), proponho, antes da sugestão de remoção de um tag que não tenha explicação da sua utilização de questões, dois possíveis procedimentos:

- Adicionar uma definição à utilização do tag (a ser, possivelmente, discutida com outros elementos no meta da comunidade - dependendo das regras existentes) e, aí, em função da definição obtida, propor a remoção ou não fazer nada.
- Questionar o utilizador do porquê da utilização desse tag específico - que, a ser válida (validez esta a definir com base em regras específicas - assumindo que ainda não o foi feito), pode ser adicionado à definição da utilização do tag. A não ser válida, remover o tag.

Comment: Gonçalo, quando falas de "mapeamento de tags" é disto que falas? https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/tags

Comment: @ANeveswantspeaceforMonica Não. Com essa expressão falo de algo a ser usado pela equipa de moderadores, por exemplo uma estrutura em árvore, que permita, entre outras, identificar as áreas que um tag esteja a cobrir por forma a remover redundâncias.

Comment: Eu não entendi se Isso é uma proposta de alteração do site mesmo ou se é uma espécie de guideline...

Comment: @JorgeB. a ideia é contribuir para uma guideline a ser utilizada neste tipo de situações específicas, por forma a facilitar interações e inclusivé o processo de moderação.

Comment: @GoncaloPeressupportsMonica sendo assim parece-me ser uma boa ideia sim senhor.

Answer (score 1):

Por acaso, fui eu que fiz a proposta de mudar um tag à tua pergunta.

<del>A lógica foi simples: acho que o tag `origem-histórica` devia ser sinónimo com o tag `etimologia`. A etimologia como disciplina das humanidades está solidamente establecida, é na sua própria definição o estudo da "origem-histórica" das palavras. (Em termos do stackexchange em Português acho que o mais correcto é tornar as tags sinónimas, o que requer um utilizador com a reputação necessária.)</del> Edit: [reparei que já houve uma reflexão sobre a possivel fusão destes tags aqui](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204/are-the-tags-origem-hist%C3%B3rica-origem-and-etimologia-synonyms).

Por isso a tag `neologismos` pareceu-me mais adequada que `etimologia` ou `origem-histórica`, por se tratar de uma expressão contemporânea, na qual a primeira palavra é `estrangeirismo`, a segunda `contração`, e a terceira é passível de ser considerada `gíria` .

Por fim, eu deixava a pedido/sugestão a quem quiser contribuir para definir os `tags` de ter o cuidado de incluir citações dos autores das gramáticas de referência da língua Portuguêsa. Como um Lindley Cintra, Celso Cunha, Evanildo Bechara, etc...

(Devo admitir, que o preciosismo do edit para mudar a tag, foi não só em vista do que acabei de explicar, mas também para ganhar o badge. De ambos os modos, parece-me válido o gesto.)

Comment: bad_coder eu ia comentar, mas acho que já entendeste a diferença entre as duas.

Comment: Sim já percebi @JorgeB. Agradeço a amabilidade, só me juntei ao site ontem e ainda estou a ambientar-me a esta nova realidade :)

Comment: sê bem-vindo então :) É bom ver pessoas a chegarem e a serem assim participativos :)